# how to design android app for both 2.3 and 4?

Tags: android, user-interface

I started developing of a new Andoird app and would like it to work on both 2.3 and before and on the newer versions such as 4.0.
I understand some UI elements do not exist on 2.3 but i dont want my app to look old style.
how do I combine?

Comment: This can be quite an involved topic, you can start by reading the Developers Guide's [Creating Backward-Compatible UIs](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is:

1) Declare a separate minimum and target SDK version:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

2) Then use libraries such as [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and the [Google support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). They contain code that backports UI elements from newer version to later Android versions.

But in general, you'll want to restrict your code to things that are available in 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for [Sherlock ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It provides ActionBar UI for older Android Version.

And here is the sample demo in Google Play take a look at it [Sherlock ActionBar Sample Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos&hl=en)